# Scope of This in a React/ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having some trouble understanding the scope of `this` inside of ES6 classes. Here, I have component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      credentials: {
        v: '3.exp',
        key: null,
      },
      coordinates: {
        lat: 51.5258541,
        lng: -0.08040660000006028,
      },
    };

    Meteor.call('googleMapsApiKey', (err, res) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({ key: res });
      }
    });
  }

  onMapCreated(map) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(() => {
        this.setState({
          coordinates: {
            lat: this.lat,
            lng: this.lng,
          },
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('geolocation not supported');
    }

    map.setOptions({
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });
  }

...
```

I get a error on line 33, which is in the `onMapCreated(map)` function, specifically the call to `this.setState`.

[image]

I suspect I'm missing sort of binding, or that the scope of this refers to `navigator.geolocation` and therefore no longer references the class. What do you guys think?

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 3):

It's not the issue of ES6, it's the binding issue or React. You should bind your method in the constructor of React:

```
this.onMapCreated = this.onMapCreated.bind(this);
```

So that `this` can be recognized in your method.

Well, maybe it's the issue of ES6, see this [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) of React:

> With React, every method is automatically bound to its component instance (except when using ES6 class syntax).

Comment: Well, one could argue that it is rather an "issue" of JavaScript, because that's how JavaScript works.

Comment: ...or `this.onMapCreated = () => this.onMapCreated();`, or (experimentally supported in babeljs),  `this.onMapCreated = this::this.onMapCreated;`

Comment: *"maybe it's the issue of ES6"* JavaScript has always worked this way. This is not new behavior in ES6.

Comment: @spender I don't understand why this can work, could you show me some link of that?

Comment: @Qianyue Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this and https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/05/14/function-bind

Comment: @spender Thank you so much!

Comment: awesome, an example of the utility of the traditionals function() methods